# How do you convert a JPanel to a File?

Tags: java, image, swing, file, jpanel

How do you convert a `JPanel` to a `File`? My panel has a moving `Image` and I want to get individual frames.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `BufferedImage` of the panel at different points in time and then save the image to a file.

The basic logic for this would be:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
panel.print( g2d );
g2d.dispose();
ImageIO.write(...);
```

Check out the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class for convenience methods that implement the above functionality.

Of course this won't be very efficient since you need a completely new image for each frame.

Comment: You'd be better using `print` or `printAll` instead of `paint`, as it doesn't involve double buffering ... and doesn't throw exceptions if the component isn't realised on the screen ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, not using the double buffer makes sense. (code changed). I have never had a problem with an Exception (platform differences?) if the component isn't realised although there are painting issues. Basically I found the size of components is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. The ScreenImage class handles the sizes for you by invoking layout code.

Comment: I've had it through `NullPointerException`, but it probably has to do with the fact that it wasn't added to any parent at all, so it had issues with setting up the double buffer ... or something, I just found `print` and `printAll` to be more reliable in these case :P

Comment: @camickr I don't understand the "g2d.dispose()" and the "ImageIO.write(...)" lines of code. Can you explain them? Thanks!